# Find Monotony of $(fx)$ from the equation of $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have $f'(x)$ drawn on graph and
I've deduced that its linear equation of the form $f'(x)=-3x+3$.

Question is:

$f(x)$ is increasing when $x \in $ ...... ?

---

> [image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6hI0.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the equation for $f'(x)$ ? Generally f(x) will be increasing when it's derivative is bigger than 0.

Comment: I will upload an image for the question

Comment: i need 10 rep to post image -_-

Comment: Haha, either do some good and get rep or look at the graph of f'(x) and determine the places where it is positive like @Steven Stewart-Gallus said.

Comment: added a link for it check it please

Comment: Ah, I see.  Try finding out when f'(x) gets negative. (for what x). At that point f(x) will start decreasing instead of increasing.

Comment: That do it so it's from ]-infinity , 1 [ .. and that's the correct answer .. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f'(x)$ is positive $f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: the question needs the interval where it's increasing on